# What does the notation of $X_n:=n1_{(0,\frac1n)}$ in the following example mean?

Tags: measure-theory, notation, definition

I don't understand the **notation** of the following term 
$$
X_n:=n1_{(0,\frac1n)}
$$

It comes from this specific problem:

> Let $P$ be uniform distribution on $[0,1]$ and let $X_n:=n1_{(0,\frac1n)}$
>   Then $X_n(w) \to 0$ for every $\omega$, but $E[X_n]=1$ for each $n$.

Comment: what $exactly$ is your problem? is it really just about the notation?

Comment: the problem is different but first I need to understand notation in the example as this is not consistent what I learned in class

Comment: alright then, maybe you edit the tag then, it is a bit misleading - besides the given answers, you can also check for *indicator function* or *characteristic function*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$f(x)=n\cdot \boldsymbol 1_{(0,\frac{1}{n})}(x)=\begin{cases}n&x\in (0,\frac{1}{n})\\0& \text{otherwise}\end{cases}$$

Comment: So in this case $X_1=1$ and the rest $X_n$ would be zeros as for example $X_2=2$ would not be in $0,1/2$ right?

Comment: not very clear. $X_1=1$ in $(0,1)$ and $0$ outside of $(0,1)$, $X_2=2$ in $(0,1/2)$ and $0$ outside of $(0,1/2)$. $X_3=3$ in $(0,1/3)$ and $0$ outside...

Comment: So how do they  get $E(X_n)$=1 it $X_n$ is increasing

Comment: $E[X_n]=n\int_0^{1/n}dx=n\cdot \frac{1}{n}=1$

Comment: Just a question a little bit not related but $\liminf E[X_n]=1$ as $E[X_n]=1$. But lets say I change $n$ to $n^2$ in $X_n$equation, then  $\liminf E[X_n]=\infty$ as $E[X_n]=n$ right?

Comment: yes since you also have $\lim E[X_n]=n$. But if you set $X_n=(-1)^n n \boldsymbol 1_{(0,\frac{1}{n})} $ (more interesting), then you get $E[X_n]=(-1)^n$ and thus $\liminf E[X_n]=-1$ and $\limsup E[X_n]=1$

Answer (score 2):

$1_A$ is the so called characteristic function. It is defined by

$1_A(x) = 1$ if $x \in A$

$1_A(x) = 0$ if $x \notin A$